# Get custom sizeof of std::function's variadic template argument types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, std-function

I have a variadic template function that accepts std::function with variadic types. I want to find total `sizeof` of those types that `std::function` has, except that I want to treat `double` and `float` types as special, where `sizeof(double) == 100` and `sizeof(float) == 50`.

Here is pseudo-code (doesn't compile)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

// terminating case for T=double
template<>
size_t getSize<double>()
{
    return 100;
}

// terminating case for T=float
template<>
size_t getSize<float>()
{
    return 50;
}

// terminating case for T being anything else
template<class T>
size_t getSize<T>()
{
    return sizeof(T);
}

// recursive case
template<class T, class ...S>
size_t getSize<T, ...S>()
{
    return getSize<T>() + getSize<S>();
}

template <class ...T>
void print_function_arg_custom_size(std::function<void(T...)> f)
{
    size_t totalSize = 0;
    // get size recursively
    totalSize = getSize<T>(); 

    std::cout << "totalSize: " << totalSize << std::endl;
}

void foo(uint8_t a, uint16_t b, uint32_t c, double d)
{
    // noop
}

int main()
{
    std::function<void(uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, double)> f = foo;
    print_function_arg_custom_size<uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, double>(f);

    return 0;
}
```

One of the issues I'm having with this is that `getSize` doesn't like my template specialization.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of errors :

```
template<class T>
size_t getSize<T>()
{
    return sizeof(T);
}
```

You don't need to provide a "specialization list" since it isn't a specialization. Also, since parameter packs can be empty, the compiler can't choose between the overloads `getSize<T>` and `getSize<T, S...>`. To fix it, make these changes:

```
template <typename T>
size_t getSize()
{
    return sizeof(T); 
}

// recursive case
template<class T, class U, class ...S>
size_t getSize()
{
    return getSize<T>() + getSize<U, S...>();
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75932212238134aa).

Comment: in more [C++14 fashion](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Uf0H8rlCRfEcbH1b), or even in [C++1z fashion](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hXzQz3VAsRfI2QFW)